# Determining if this mapping is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and let $C(X)$ denote the vector space of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. For $f,g \in C(X)$, let $$ d_{\infty} (f,g) = \sup \left\{ |f(x) - g(x)| \mid x \in X \right\}.$$

Now let $C^1([-1,1])$ denote the vector space of functions from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that are differentiable atleast once and have a continuous derivative. Is the following map then continuous: $$ D : C^1([-1,1]) \mapsto \mathbb{R}: f \mapsto D(f) = f'(0) $$ ? We consider the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, and the $d_{\infty}$ metric on $C^1([-1,1])$.

**Attempt:** I was trying to prove that $D$ is continuous in $f \in C^1([-1,1])$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then we need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall g \in C^1([-1,1])$ with $d_{\infty}(f,g) < \delta$ it follows that $$ | D(f) - D(g)| = |f'(0) - g'(0)| < \epsilon. $$

I'm not really sure how to do this. I was trying to use some properties of $f$. Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous. Since it is defined on a  closed and bounded interval, it is also uniformly continuous. So there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \sigma$ if $x,y \in [-1,1]$ and $|x-y| < \delta$. But I'm not sure how to relate this to $d_{\infty} (f,g) < \delta$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false: a linear map between normed vector spaces is continuous if and only if it is bounded on the unit ball. Let's consider the *norm* $$\lVert f\rVert_\infty:=d_\infty(f,0)$$ which *induces* the distance $d_\infty$.

The functions $g_\alpha(x)=\frac2\pi\arctan(\alpha x)$ clearly satisfy $\lVert g_\alpha\rVert_\infty\le1$, but $g'_\alpha(0)=\dfrac{2\alpha}{\pi}$. Therefore $$\sup_{\lVert f\rVert_\infty\le1}\lvert f'(0)\rvert=+\infty$$ which means that $D$ is not continuous.

**Added:** In fact, there is a metric ad hoc which is usually put on $C^1[-1,1]$ to make your map (and others) continuous. It's $$d_{C^1}(f,g):=d_\infty(f,g)+d_\infty(f',g')$$ which is induced by the norm $\lVert f\rVert_{C^1}:=\lVert f\rVert_\infty+\lVert f'\rVert_\infty$

Comment: So you take for $g(x)$ the zero function, and for $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(\alpha x)$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, I don't use a sequential argument. I use a different characterisation of continuity of linear functionals (the one I cite in the first line) and show that it does not hold in your case.